# I can't use classList in Js. Can anyone help me with this

Tags: javascript, html, css

so this is the line of JS I have written.

```
function jumpPlayer() {
    let character = document.getElementById("player");

    character.classList.add("jumpPlayer");
}
```

fairly simple, there is a Id called 'player' and I want to add class called 'jumpPlayer' when a button is clicked but something is going wrong.

this is the error message

```
script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at jumpPlayer (script.js:4:15)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html:19:50)
```

by the way here is the html

```
<body>
    <div class="camera">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="player" id="player"></div>
        <div class="enemy"></div>
        <div class="ground"></div>
        <div class="foreground"></div>

        <div class="jump" onclick="jumpPlayer()"></div>
    </div>



    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')` is your answer: `classList` isn't the problem, but `character` - it can't get the classList of a null element. What does your html look like? How is `jumpPlayer()` called?

Comment: Seems to work fine assuming an element with that Id exists.  https://jsfiddle.net/865f0upo/  I think @user1599011 probably nailed it.